# Angularjs Which Param Had Changed

Tags: angularjs

I am usin routeUpdate to watch if search changed:

```
$scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function (next, current) {
    $scope.updatePointDetails($scope.point.Id, moment($scope.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    ...
});
```

Can i get which parameter in search had changed, anf maybe old and new value?

Comment: what do you mean by 'search changed'?

Comment: Why don't you use the $scope.$watch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source code the $routeUpdate is called with:

`$rootScope.$broadcast('$routeUpdate', last);`

`last` is the last route. This has the `params` object that you can check.

Check if:

```
$scope.$on('$routeUpdate', function (last) {
     //check last.params has the old values
})
```